# Sound delay on playback start

Tags: linux, pulseaudio, manjaro

I experience annoying problem with audio, any help is appreciated!

Problem:
Sound delays 2-3 seconds on playback start. It present only on first start after idle, works fine if I switch between sources while one of them is playing or just stopped.

Manjaro linux, kernel 5.10.
Intel audio card. Auto mute disabled.
Added `intel_iommu=igfx_off` to grub params. Tried to apply solutions https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting , but nothing helped(or I just missed something)

Hint: worked fine on previous hardware. Switched from dell xps 9570 to 9500(i5-8300H -> i5-10300H)

Pulseaudio configs:

```
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
rescue-streams = yes
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-14.2/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = 
log-level = notice
resample-method = auto
avoid-resampling = no
enable-remixing = yes
remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
remixing-produce-lfe = no
remixing-consume-lfe = no
lfe-crossover-freq = 0
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 4
default-fragment-size-msec = 25
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 8000
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 200000
```

Comment: Check if this works: log off, `Ctrl + Alt + F2` -> Log in, `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.bak`, reboot.

Comment: yes, this ^ worked.  Thank you @ArtemS.Tashkinov , if you add it as an answer, I will mark it a solution.

Comment: Possibly related: *[How to fix first play of sound delayed, missed or muffled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310138/how-to-fix-first-play-of-sound-delayed-missed-or-muffled)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this works:

1. Log off
2. Ctrl + Alt + F2 -> Log in
3. `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.bak`
4. `reboot`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds this in the future and it doesn't solve their issue (like me), my chimp-brain workaround was to make an audio file of silence and set it to loop as my first cue. This seems to keep things alive so other cues fire instantly.

Comment: [An answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310138/how-to-fix-first-play-of-sound-delayed-missed-or-muffled/1310141#1310141) claims this may not be sufficient.